# How to enable all permision in applet?

Tags: java, security, permissions, applet

I created Applet for Voice recording with functionality of Record Stop Play Save.. When I run same program on Applet Viewer then its working fine with all functionality but When i am trying to run Applet on IE i.e Internet Explorer then its returned with:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied javax.sound.sampled.Audio Permission
```

So what should I do? (I also converted Java file in Jar) still not working .. so How to grant Permission in Java? Or there are any other solution for this problem?

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. I recommend you to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to learn how to ask a good and well-received question. I would assume you forgot to add `AudioPermission` to your Applet. It's hard to say though without seeing any of your code. I would recommend you to add that. Also on a sidenote, Applets are generally considered to be dead and are not supported by most modern browers.

Comment: for starters, you should stop using Applets. All major browsers stopped supporting them, and those browsers that haven't yet, soon will.

Comment: You probably cannot use the applet unless you can sign it with a trusted digital certificate and lower IE's security settings. You could have a look at Java Web Start which is a technology replacing applets.

Comment: *"Or there are any other solution for this problem?"* To the problem of some random web page eavesdropping? Sure. As mentioned by others, browser manufacturers have dropped support for plug-ins. The Java plug-in also handles JWS apps., so @MickMnemonic's suggestion to use it instead, really solves nothing.

Comment: @MickMnemonic yeah it worked ...its running after signing Jar...and its working properly without error...Thanx friend...and thanx to all for paying attention